# Converting topological problems to algebraic problems

Tags: category-theory

We can convert topological problems to algebraic problems by functors. Can you give  any example about this situation?

Comment: Shown effort: none. Quality of the question: obviously way too broad; answers can be found simply by using google or by reading ANY book on algebraic topology

Comment: If you ask for an example then very specific answers are possible. In my view this question is not too broad and testifies of a healthy curiosity.

Comment: @drhab It seems that you don't know a lot about algebraic topology. Almost any result of algebraic topology would be a valid answer. It should be made CW or closed as too broad.

Comment: @Laters What is the meaning of CW in your comment? (not closure-finite and equipped with weak topology I guess).

Comment: @drhab: it means community wiki, I thought that this would be a standard notation.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the question:

> Are $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ homeomorphic for $n\neq m$?

When $n=1$ and $m>1$, the answer is not too difficult, since $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\}$ is connected for $m>1$ while $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not.  However, for general $n,m$, the question is much more difficult to handle.

One of the main ideas of Algebraic Topology is using "algebraic invariants".  Formally, we wish to build functors from some sufficiently nice subcategory of $\mathbf{Top}$, like the category of compactly-generated hausdorff spaces $\mathbf{CGHaus}$ (this is because $\mathbf{Top}$ has some poor properties as a category), into some "algebraic" category like $\mathbf{Grp}$ or $\mathbf{AbGrp}$.

For example, there is a functor $\pi_1:\mathbf{Top}_\bullet \rightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$ given by sending a pointed topological space $(X,x_0)$ to the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.  A slightly simpler example is the functor $\pi_0:\mathbf{Top}\rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ defined by sending a topological space $X$ to $\pi_0 X$, the set of path-connected components of $X$.

Why do we do this?  We do this because if, given two categories $\mathscr{C},\mathscr{D}$ and a functor $F:\mathscr{C}\rightarrow \mathscr{D}$, then if there exists an isomorphism $\varphi:c\rightarrow c'$ between the objects $c$ and $c'$ of $\mathscr{C}$, then $F(\varphi):F(c)\rightarrow F(c')$ is also an isomorphism.  As such, if $F(c)$ and $F(c')$ *aren't* isomorphic, then we can conclude that $c$ and $c'$ aren't isomorphic!

As far as our specific question above is concerned, the algebraic invariant we want to make use of is that of simplicial homology.  The category $\mathbf{Csim}$ is that of simplicial complexes, and $\mathbf{Ch}_\bullet(\mathbf{AbGrp})$ the category of chain complexes over $\mathbf{AbGrp}$.  Then we can send a simplicial complex $K$ to its simplicial homology chain complex, giving a functor.

Simplicial complexes aren't topological spaces, but there exists a functor $|\cdot|:\mathbf{Csim}\rightarrow \mathbf{Top}$ called the geometric realization, and it can be shown that if $|K|$ and $|K'|$ are homotopy equivalent, then the homology of $K$ is equal to the homology of $K'$.  Using this, we get a functor from the category of triangulable topological spaces (those that are homeomorphic to the realization of some simplicial complex) to $\mathbf{Ch}_\bullet(\mathbf{AbGrp})$.

$\mathbb{S}^n$, the $n$-sphere, is triangulable and has homology given by
$$H_m(\mathbb{S}^n)=\begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & i=0,n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

So to finally apply all of this to our original question, suppose $\mathbb{R}^n\cong \mathbb{R}^m$.  Then we can show that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\cong \mathbb{R}^m\setminus \{0\}$.  $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ is homotopy-equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^n$, so our homeomorphism would descend to showing that $\mathbb{S}^n$ and $\mathbb{S}^m$ are homotopy-equivalent.  But the homologies of homotopy-equivalent spaces are equal, so if $n\neq m$ (and $m\neq 0$) we have $\mathbb{Z}=H_n(\mathbb{S}^n)=H_n(\mathbb{S}^m)=0$, giving a contradiction.  (If $m=0$, then just switch the role of $m$ and $n$.)  Thus, $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ when $n\neq m$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they downvoted?  I don't even think the answer is up long enough to fully read this answer...

Comment: Probably a serial downvoter. I compensated.

Comment: @drhab I thought that might be the case because the other answer was also downvoted seconds after my own.  Thanks

Comment: " the question is much more difficult to handle." is simply wrong, and it is an opinion shared by many people that the general case it just the natural continuation of the low dimensional case. Also it is clear from the question that the last half of the answer is useless to the op (clearly he is aware of this!).

Comment: @Laters The only proofs I know that don't invoke some degree of algebraic topology use the notion of topological dimension.  It takes quite a bit to develop the theory and then to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ actually has topological dimension $n$.  Personally, I feel that the homology is conceptually simpler and that once it has been introduced, it is extremely easy to prove the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, can you advice any book which has an more clear example? Because I newly start to this area and examples a bit complicated for me.

Comment: @irem Well, the first step would be to make sure you have a good foundation in general topology, and only then would the next step be to move on to algebraic topology.  Which books would be best for you probably depend on your background, so for that reason alone I'd suggest you peruse some of the other questions on book recommendations or ask your own.  Personally, I used Munkres' Topology and Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: @irem as I pointed out in the comments, you can take any book in algebraic topology. The book which stresses the "functorial" point of view is Spanier's Algebraic topology.

Comment: @irem I hope that Seifert and Threlfall's *A Textbook of Topology* makes a good exposition to you, and Bott and Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*. Personally I think Hatcher is somewhat wordy.

Comment: thank you @FrankScience Iwill look them

Comment: @irem I expanded the answer to detail the functors used to answer the motivating question, in case you are interested.  There are obviously many details and proofs that need to be filled in, but that's the work for a course in algebraic topology.

Comment: thank you @hayden. I must learn more detail about this area.

Comment: How $\mathbb R$ is not simply-connected ? (It is even contractible, hence has the homotopy type of a point, right ?) I imagine you wanted to say something as : punctured $\mathbb R$ isn't connected while punctured $\mathbb R^m$ ($m>1$) is.

Comment: @Pece Sorry, you're right, don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: Let $B^n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ denote the closed unit ball, and let $S^{n-1}$ denote its boundary. Show that there is no continuous map $f:B^n\to S^{n-1}$ such that$$f|_{S^{n-1}}=id.$$

Comment: Probably a serial downvoter. I compensated.

Comment: Probably not. $ / $

Comment: @Laters Are you the downvoter? If so then why is any argumentation lacking?

Comment: @drhab this answer doesn't even mention the functor (and so it doesn't really address the question). And I can think of at least 3 functors which would be able to solve the problem. Probably homology is intended.

Comment: @Laters Thank you for this. I dislike downvotes without argumentation but now this is not one of them anymore.

Comment: @Laters As you commented yourself, the OP asked a very broad question and didn't show any effort. I figured that there was no point in giving a detailed answer, before the OP got deeper into the matter on their own. If you don't like it, well, I'm sorry. Most of my answers on this cite are (considerably) more detailed. In this case, I really believe that my answer is appropriate, just as it is.

Comment: @drhab I do not understand: if Laters is the downvoter for the 2 answers, why I do not see a loss of 2 points in his reputation?

Comment: @magma Neither do I. When I first arrived here I noticed that both answers had been downvoted without any comments and reacted on this without doing any profound research.